# Is it possible to explicitly declare which project to use bq slot in BigqueryOperator?

Tags: google-bigquery, airflow

Says I have composer airflow run under GCP project named project-central (as source project).
I have a lot of task instances using BigqueryOperator to generate a table for multiple projects (as target table), for example:

1. project-1
2. project-2
3. project-3

From what I understand, BigqueryOperator by default will run SQL using bq slot from which composer is running (based on the example above project-central).

With the aim of:

1. to split the resources,
2. to prevent the hit limit of bq slot in project-central, and
3. to have cost attribution

I need to have the task instance BigqueryOperator running using bq slot of the target table.
So if the target table is project-2, BigqueryOperator uses bq slot from project-2 instead of project-central.
Is it possible to have those settings in BigqueryOperator params?

I see params `bigquery_conn_id (str) – reference to a specific BigQuery hook` from this link https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.6/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator/index.html
But is it correct to use that to set up which project to use bq slot?
If yes, what is the value of that params?
Because I can't find many examples of that, just this under the same link, and I still don't understand what that is means.

- `bigquery_conn_id='airflow-service-account'`
- `bigquery_conn_id='bigquery_default'`